# Diffrence between getExtras().getSerializable() and getSerializableExtra()

Tags: android, android-intent

I am having confusion between

```
intent.getSerializableExtra (String name)
```

and

```
intent.getExtras().getSerializable (String key)
```

Can we use them interchangeably, or both of them have their own specific scenarios?
If so, what are those scenarios when we can use `getSerializableExtra (String name)`
and when we can use `getExtras().getSerializable (String key)`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both do the same thing. `getSerializableExtra` is a method of `Intent` (you have to call it on `Intent` instance) `getSerializable` is a method of `Bundle` (you have to call it on a `Bundle` instance)

Comment: i have used This if i m wrong please correct me 
promise = (Promises) getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("promise"); at certain places 
that was working Fine but on the other 
it causes app crash
but when i Use 
promise = (Promises) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("promise");
app is stable 
so wher is that loop hole that causing crash ?
can you brief it please ?

Comment: it is correct . Just remember if you use the intent to store the serializable object, you have to use the intent instant in order to get it back, if you put the serializable object into the bundle use getExtras().getSerializable