# What is the difference between getExtras().getSerializable(key) and getSerializableExtra(name)

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization, parcelable

As in topic I'm curious about why it got distinguished on `getExtras().getSerializable(key) and getSerializableExtra(name)`.

In both cases we receive the Serializable object. Is there any performance or deprecation issue?

Regards

Comment: possible duplicate of [Diffrence between getExtras().getSerializable() and getSerializableExtra()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701637/diffrence-between-getextras-getserializable-and-getserializableextra)

Answer (score 2):

`.getSerializable(key)` - To get data from bundle object

`.getSerializableExtra(name)` - To get data from Intent object.